# updating data in MySql database table

Tags: c#, mysql

I am creating a Windows Forms application and now at certain point I need to make a database connection, I have inserted the values to database easily, but now its not updating my data, I am using following query for this purpose:

```
MySqlCommand sda = new MySqlCommand(@"Update shedulling.tablelayout1 set date = '" 
    + date + "',line = " + line + ",col1 = '" + first_textbox.text + "', col2 = '" 
    + sec_textbox.text + "',col3_textbox.text = '" + thi_textbox.text 
    + "',col4_textbox.text = '" + four + "' where date = '" + date + "' AND line = '" 
    + line.ToString() + "' ", conn);
```

`conn` is a connection string which is written fine, and `date` and `line` are string and integer values send as an argument to this function.

Comment: Could be a probem with the timeformat. There are many formats possible. Watch here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: Is it really called "shedulling" which is spelled incorrectly? What error are you getting? Also you need to read up on SQL injection prevention, this application is very susceptible to a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed single quotes in `line` part. Change it like this `line = '" + line + "'`.

Also there is one more notable thing in your code: you are trying to find the record in the table that is not exist yet in `where` clause `where date = '" + date + "' AND line = '" + line.ToString() + "'` note in this line `date` and `line` are the new values not old values so no rows affected in the update query. You should use old values of `date` and `line` in the `where` clause.

Also you should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the code, there must be INSERT statement executing somewhere in your code.

**UPDATE:** If "line" is integer variable then you need to convert it into string. You have converted it after WHERE clause but not after SET clause.

You may want to post some more code to get exact answer.